# make a image appear and disappear

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to create a responsive image that when to click on it another image opens and when you click on the new picture it goes away... disappears. 
thanks !!

this is my code:

```
 <div class="item">
    <div id="img1"><"https://www.istockphoto.com/il/photos/lion-cub?excludenudity=true&sort=mostpopular&mediatype=photography&phrase=lion%20cub" /></div>

    <div class="artical1"></div>
    <img src="http://www.interload.co.il/upload/5439335.jpg" id="image1" onclick=diffImage(this) />

    <img src="http://www.interload.co.il/upload/9659133.jpg" onclick="this.style.display='none';"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Also, the formatting is broken. Please rephrase and fix accordingly. Until then: are you, by any chance, looking for something like a [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) script?

Comment: Can you please add what you have tried so far?

Comment: The element inside your `#img1` is not valid HTML whatsoever. Plus, all the `div`s we see here seem irrelevant to the problem. The inline-Javascript refers to a function called `diffImage()` but I don't see that function anywhere. You should show us that implementation. Also, when you say "it goes away", does _it_ refer to the first image, or the one that opened? Sorry, this is really a low quality question right now. Please check out [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The below code works in a similar approach to yours.

I have used the `visibility` CSS property instead of `display` and added the correct javascript into the `onclick` event of the first image

```html
 <div class="item">

    <div class="artical1"></div>
    <img src="http://www.interload.co.il/upload/5439335.jpg" id="image1" onclick="document.getElementById('other-image').style.visibility='visible'" />

    <img id="other-image" src="http://www.interload.co.il/upload/9659133.jpg" onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden';"/>
</div>
```

I would recommend looking in to javascript in more detail to be able to do this in a more reproducible way.